# Forcing a dynamically loaded javascript to not cache on google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, browser-cache, dynamic-loading

I'm working on a google maps loader (using the google maps javascript API).  I want to dynamically add points to a path as and when they come available.  **Edit**: *The webpage and javascript are stored and loaded locally and not through a web server*.

To this end I have created an external javascript file in which I put the data I want to use.

I load the java script object using a great trick I found elsewhere on stackoverflow:

```
function loadjsfile( filename, callback )
{
    var fileref = document.createElement( 'script' );
    fileref.setAttribute( "type", "text/javascript" );
    fileref.setAttribute( "src", filename );

    var done = false;
    fileref.onload  = fileref.onreadystatechange    = function()
    {
        if( !done && ( !this.readyState 
                                || this.readyState == "loaded" 
                                || this.readyState == "complete") )
        {
                done = true;

                // Continue your code
                callback();

                // Handle memory leak in IE
                fileref.onload = fileref.onreadystatechange = null;
                document.getElementsByTagName( "script" )[0].removeChild( fileref );
        }   
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName( "script" )[0].appendChild( fileref );
}
```

This works perfectly as it waits until the external javascript has actually loaded before proceeding with the intialisation.

So thats all great it loads up fine.  I then set a 5 second timeout which reloads the external javascript file.  This is where I have an issue.  Google chrome is re-loading the external javascript file from cache instead of going straight to disk.  This is a huge pain as it means that my map path doesn't update as it goes along.  I really need it to.

When I refreshed the entire page then it was fine it reloaded the javascript but the flicker was very annoying (and it forced the map back to the "initial" state).  This new method would work perfectly provided I could force it to re-load the javascript file everytime.

So can anyone help me?

I'm very new to Javascript (I'm mainly a C++ coder) so apologies if I'm asking something stupid :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If noone else has other ideas, try appending a random number as a query string to the filename. This will tell the script the file is **new** and should force a reload.

**Basically generate a random number each time.**

```
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*80000);
```

**So you code would look something like**

```
function loadjsfile( filename, callback )
{
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*80000);
    var fileref = document.createElement( 'script' );
    fileref.setAttribute( "type", "text/javascript" );
    fileref.setAttribute( "src", filename + "?r=" + rnd ); // note this line

    // other code...
}
```

Comment: Sweet that seems to work.  Can you explain why this works though?  If I understand correctly, its sending a query to the javascript but I don't understand why that would force a reload.

Comment: Because the browser thinks it's a different file, i.e. a dynamically generated page because of the changing URL. I'm not sure if the browser would try and cache each and every ***random* url**, but it might be worth a test with a smaller sample.

Comment: Ok I think I understand.  As a query sent to the browser the browser has no idea what exactly the server will return.  Therefore it can't possibly use a cached version because the query could return something completely different.  The query string is just ignore however because what the web browser doesn't know is that I'm not doing anything so complicated.  Is that right?

Comment: @Goz, Yep you're onto it :) A query string **could** produce different contents therefore the browser doesn't cache it. Don't forget you can also increase the random size by adding to the multiplier if you're concerned about hitting the same number twice :)

Comment: Hate to be nitpicky, but using a random number has a chance (however slight it might be) to still serve up the cached version. new Date().getTime() may be better.

Comment: The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132613/forcing-a-dynamically-loaded-javascript-to-not-cache-on-google-chrome#comment19636768_4132659) using the development tools to invalidate the entire cache is the correct answer. This is a hack.

Answer (score 1):

You could (if your file is hosted on an apache webserver) add a .htaccess file to the directory, containing your script file with the content:

```
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
```

This will prevent the file from being cached.

There are also other ways to send these header informations.

Comment: Sorry I should have stated that this is being done from a local store.  I have updated my question.

Comment: If you're doing local development with google chrome, then disable cacheing while you're in development. Do this by:

Bring up the development tools (ctrl + shift + i)
Click the settings cog at the bottom right.
General tab.
Disable cache.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a random number as Marko suggested, you can put date.now() which is absolutely always different with each new upload and writing is more compact.
Tested and works with Chrome, Opera, Edge and Firefox.

```
<script>
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.src='./mymodule.js'+ '?t=' + Date.now();
document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```